# "Access denied" generating server key in first-network Hyperledger fabric sample

Tags: file-permissions, hyperledger-fabric, sample

I have followed all the steps to build my first-network sample as documented in:
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

I am on Windows 10, 64 bits, having everything set up as per the document, using the Docker Quickstart Terminal. After the installation of binaries and fabric-samples (exactly as documented) I am trying to run the "first-network" sample.  I get "Access Denied" generating the network artifacts:

```
$ ../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
Error generating local MSP for {peer0 peer0.org1.example.com       [peer0.org1.example.com peer0]}:
rename crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\peers\peer0.org1.example.com\tls\83767f495f56cac98da0a0ce1acf447b839f1e3e9c21d11a87e21125d81294fa_sk crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\peers\peer0.org1.example.com\tls\server.key: Access is denied.
```

Of course, I get the same result with

```
./byfn.sh -m generate
```

Here are the tls files:

```
$ ls -l  ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/
total 9
-rw-r--r-- 1 kkova 197609 241 Nov 30 07:41 7dcd83ec4aabc1b549d76f120ba6954053cc3a452889646fa9997477142a5357_sk
-rw-r--r-- 1 kkova 197609 855 Nov 30 07:41 ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 kkova 197609 895 Nov 30 07:41 server.crt
```

Comment: Can you run "../bin/cryptogen version" and post the output?

Comment: Also, are you using Docker Toolbox or Docker for Windows?  Seems like you might be using Docker Toolbox as I don't think Docker for Windows has the Quickstart terminal.  I'd suggest moving to Docker for Windows if that's the case

Comment: Cryptogen output: `$ ../bin/cryptogen version
cryptogen:
 Version: 1.1.0-preview
 Go version: go1.9
 OS/Arch: windows/amd64` I used Docker Toolbox. Tried to install Docker for Windows, but it fails with a Hyper V related error (_Unable to stop: The running command stopped ....: The specified module 'Hyper-V' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory._). Searched for solutions, but it seems with my BIOS not supporting Hyper V, I can not fix this. I will search further OR have to use Docker Toolbox.